# display automatically generated option for text field with chosen function

Tags: php, jquery, html

Basically, in my site I want a tag box like Stack Overflow so I searched for it and I found the solution in JQuery `chosen();` function. It is working fine with predefined options like:

```
<select id="tag" multiple="true" style="width:400px;">
    <option>Choose...</option>
    <option>jQuery</option>
    <option selected="selected">MooTools</option>
    <option>Prototype</option>
    <option selected="selected">Dojo Toolkit</option>
</select>
```

But I want to retrieve values of tags those are automatically searched from database. I have no idea how to do that so help me.

Comment: Do you want to create the options from the database when the page is first opened, or dynamically modify the menu?

Comment: dynamically modify the menu

Comment: Then you need to learn about AJAX. There are many tutorials on the web.

Comment: Ok thanks.Can you send me link of tutorial that can solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where the tutorials are. Use google.